# Need to use IConvertible in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have some code in .Net4.0 and .Net4.5 testing if an object variable implements `IConvertible`. If, then I use the various `ToString` overloads.

I also have a project targeting `WinRT (Windows store app)` which of course doesn't seem to be able to resolve `IConvertible` despite e.g. `Int32` actually does implement it.

Test case can be found here: http://danielwertheim.se/2013/09/22/iconvertible-in-winrtnetfxmetro/

So, is there something I can do to actually be able to use `IConvertible` in a Windows store app project?

Comment: i got a similar problem, have you found a solution jet?

Comment: There's no solution, for me I had to work around it. It seems like depending on what device you actually run the code, the JIT will give you different results. Waiting on confirmation on that though, but you don't seem to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. We are all left hanging on this one by Microsoft design decisions of subset WinRT of .Net.

As seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vsddd.110%29.aspx `IConvertible` can be used in PCL but not if the PCL targets Windows store.